# How can I programmatically access the contents of a Dovecot mailbox in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, email, postfix, webserver, dovecot

I just set up `postfix` and `dovecot` on a `CentOS 7` server [using this tutorial](https://www.vultr.com/docs/simple-mailserver-postfix-dovecot-sieve-centos-7).  I am able to successfully create a mail record using `echo "TEST" | mail -s "testmail" youruser@localhost && tail -f /var/log/maillog`.  **But how can I access and work with the resulting email files?**

I need to configure a `java` program to process incoming email, including decomposing and processing attachment files.  This could be done using either mysql or simply raw files.  But I need to know where to have the `java` program look for the mail.

As per the tutorial, I set `mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir` in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`.  But when I type `cd /home/youruser/Maildir`, the terminal replies with `-bash: cd: Maildir: Permission denied`.  Similarly, `sudo cd /home/youruser/Maildir` simply results in the terminal ignoring the command and remaining in whatever directory it was previously in.

Answer (score 1):

In general you shouldn't have to manipulate maildir directly. Maildir is not only a directory tree with files but also a set of indexes and other supplementary files. When you create the file in the `./new` subdir you, at least, have to recreate the index of corresponding folder.

Recommended way is to use `doveadm` utility to create folders an subfolders as well as subscribe them. If you want to inject some message to the maidir, you have to use `deliver` utility that perform injection in the proper way.

If you need to read the content of maildir you have to use some IMAP library that conforms IMAP protocol. I'm not familiar with Java but I'm absolutely sure that more than one library with required functionality exists.

Raw access to the maildir is not recommended.

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA

Comment: Thank you very much.  Can you please post some links to explanations of how to do the things that you are suggesting? I need step by step instructions.  With your knowledge of the subject, I imagine that you could find some tutorials or other documentation that I would not be able to find myself.

Comment: @slm Thank you. This does not answer my question. I need to read the sender, the message text, the attached files, and possibly the sender's ip address from each email into another program. It is fine if this all goes into mysql. I can use java to get it out of mysql myself. The answer does not have to be specific to java. I just definitely need to be able to use code to view and manipulate the contents of each message. I am tempted to write another question, but I am reaching out first so as to reduce clutter of redundant questions on the site if this question can be answered in a unable way.

Comment: @CodeMed - wasn't my answer, I simply edited it.

Comment: @CodeMed Email format (MIME-multipart/encoded) is quite complex. Look for ready-to-use third-party solution instead of making you own toolset.

Comment: @Kondybas Anything that gets it into mysql would be sufficient.  Can you suggest how to get it into mysql?

Comment: @CodeMed Sorry, I never translate maildir into `mysql`. But there is `dbmail` - another POP/IMAP server that used `mysql` as backend, instead of tree on the filesystem. May be you can fetch the messages from existing storage and pass them to the `dbmail`?

Comment: @Kondybas I am not tied to dovecot or postfix.  I just need incoming mail to be accessible from a java program.  And if using a database will shield me from unnecessary complexity, that is fine.  I just really need explicit instructions for setting it up in CentOS 7.  When I google for instructions, everything is specific to other operating systems.

Comment: This did not answer my question in any way.